# Check column value for Any 6 rows out of 10 rows Kusto query language

Tags: kql

I have 10 rows with two columns Time and Count, So I want to check among those 10 rows if any 6 rows having value 0 or not ? Data sample:

| Time | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 17:23:00.000 | 70 |
| 2022-09-01 17:24:00.000 | 150 |
| 2022-09-01 17:25:00.000 | 300 |
| 2022-09-01 17:26:00.000 | 160 |
| 2022-09-01 17:27:00.000 | 210 |
| 2022-09-01 17:28:00.000 | 316 |
| 2022-09-01 17:29:00.000 | 265 |
| 2022-09-01 17:30:00.000 | 711 |
| 2022-09-01 17:31:00.000 | 185 |
| 2022-09-01 17:32:00.000 | 250 |

Comment: Required results? A single value? false/true?

Comment: true or false also fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let t = datatable(Time:datetime, Count:int)
[
    '2022-09-01 17:23:00.000' , 70
   ,'2022-09-01 17:24:00.000' ,150
   ,'2022-09-01 17:25:00.000' ,300
   ,'2022-09-01 17:26:00.000' ,160
   ,'2022-09-01 17:27:00.000' ,210
   ,'2022-09-01 17:28:00.000' ,316
   ,'2022-09-01 17:29:00.000' ,265
   ,'2022-09-01 17:30:00.000' ,711
   ,'2022-09-01 17:31:00.000' ,185
   ,'2022-09-01 17:32:00.000' ,250
]
;
t
| summarize result = countif(Count == 0) >= 6
```

| result |
| --- |
| false |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3XRTwuDIBgG8Lvgd3hvFdR4taXlcJd9hd3GDvvjIKgGZZexDz/roozUi8KP5xWfzliwoOF5s27fO5Oe294odzXWHXI4vefBqnawGSUXSsCthCPnBTYFMmBS8VIh7hAxgRwkrib/N3tvWBUxlTclRowIckTESG84i5g6mMXEtmmCHFFtmhK9kYxtGxa8uY7k8GDW8j9XSg6UWEq+MM19fxvbj4HRTHO3tPVYSmlf6VoOaA2YwVGD+AGi9rCwzgEAAA==)

Comment: Is there a way I can get results instead of boolean value ?

Comment: Please accept this answer and post a new question which includes a relevant data sample + required results